# Не могу откомпилировать файл ассемблера

Tags: c, ассемблер

Вот ошибки которые появляются при компилировании:

```
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/myOS_8.0T$ make mykernel.bin
as --32 -o interruptstubs.o interruptstubs.s
interruptstubs.s: Assembler messages:
interruptstubs.s: Warning: конец файла не в конце строки; вставлен символ новой строки
interruptstubs.s:8: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `:'
interruptstubs.s:27: Error: bad register name `%0x00+IRQ_BASE'
interruptstubs.s:28: Error: bad register name `%0x01+IRQ_BASE'
Makefile:12: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «interruptstubs.o»
make: *** [interruptstubs.o] Ошибка 1
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/myOS_8.0T$
```

а вот исходник:

```
.set IRQ_BASE, 0x20

.section .text

.extern _ZN16InterruptManager15handleInterruptEhj

.global _ZN16InterruptManager22IgnoreInterruptRequestEv:



.macro HandleException num

.global _ZN16InterruptManager16HandleException\num\()Ev
_ZN16InterruptManager15HandleException\num\()Ev:
    movb %\num, (interruptnumber)
    jmp int_bottom
.endm

.macro HandleInterruptRequest num
.global _ZN16InterruptManager26HandleInterruptRequest\num\()Ev
_ZN16InterruptManager26HandleInterruptRequest\num\()Ev:
    movb %\num + IRQ_BASE, (interruptnumber)
    jmp int_bottom
.endm

HandleInterruptRequest 0x00
HandleInterruptRequest 0x01



int_bottom:

    pusha
    pushl %ds
    pushl %es
    pushl %fs
    pushl %gs

    pushl %esp
    push (interruptnumber)
    call _Z15handleInterrupthj
    # addl $5, %esp
    movl %eax, %esp

    popl %gs
    popl %fs
    popl %es
    popl %ds
    popa

_ZN16InterruptManager22IgnoreInterruptRequestEv:

    iret

.data
    interruptnumber: .byte 0
```

Файл cpp:

```
#include "interrupts.h"


void printf(char* str);


InterruptManager::GateDescriptor InterruptManager::InterruptDescriptorTable[256];

void InterruptManager::SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(
        uint8_t interruptNumber,
        uint16_t codeSegmentSelectorOffset,
        void (*handler)(),
        uint8_t DescriptorPrivilegeLevel,
        uint8_t DescriptorType)
{

    const uint8_t IDT_DESC_PRESENT = 0x80;

    InterruptDescriptorTable[interruptNumber].handlerAddressLowBits = ((uint32_t)handler) & 0xFFFF;
    InterruptDescriptorTable[interruptNumber].handlerAddressHighBits = (((uint32_t)handler) >> 16) & 0xFFFF;
    InterruptDescriptorTable[interruptNumber].gdt_codeSegmentSelector = codeSegmentSelectorOffset;
    InterruptDescriptorTable[interruptNumber].access = IDT_DESC_PRESENT | DescriptorType | ((DescriptorPrivilegeLevel&3) << 5);
    InterruptDescriptorTable[interruptNumber].reserved = 0;

}

InterruptManager::InterruptManager(GlobalDescriptorTable* gdt)
{
    uint16_t CodeSegment = gdt->CodeSegmentSelector();
    const uint8_t IDT_INTERRUPT_GATE = 0xE;

    for(uint16_t i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(i, CodeSegment, &IgnoreInterruptRequest, 0, IDT_INTERRUPT_GATE);

    SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(0x20, CodeSegment, &HandleInterruptRequest0x00, 0, IDT_INTERRUPT_GATE);
    SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(0x21, CodeSegment, &HandleInterruptRequest0x01, 0, IDT_INTERRUPT_GATE);

    InterruptDescriptorTablePointer idt;
    idt.size = 256 * sizeof(GateDescriptor) - 1;
    idt.base = (uint32_t)InterruptDescriptorTable;
    asm volatile("lidt %0" : : "m" (idt));

}

InterruptManager::~InterruptManager()
{
}

void InterruptManager::Activate()
{
    asm("sti");
}



uint32_t InterruptManager::handleInterrupt(uint8_t interruptNumber, uint32_t esp)
{

    printf(" INTERRUPT");

    return esp;
}
```

Файл h:

```
#ifndef __INTERRUPTS_H
#define __INTERRUPTS_H

#include "types.h"
#include "port.h"
#include "gdt.h"


    class InterruptManager
    {

    protected:

        struct GateDescriptor
        {
            uint16_t handlerAddressLowBits;
            uint16_t gdt_codeSegmentSelector;
            uint8_t reserved;
            uint8_t access;
            uint16_t handlerAddressHighBits;            


        } __attribute__((packed));

        static GateDescriptor InterruptDescriptorTable[256];

        struct InterruptDescriptorTablePointer
        {
            uint16_t size;
            uint32_t base;
        } __attribute__((packed));

        static void SetInterruptDescriptorTableEntry(
            uint8_t interruptNumber,
            uint16_t codeSegmentSelectorOffset,
            void (*handler)(),
            uint8_t DescriptorPrivilegeLevel,
            uint8_t DescriptorType
        );

    public:

        InterruptManager(GlobalDescriptorTable* gdt);
        ~InterruptManager();

        void Activate();

        static uint32_t handleInterrupt(uint8_t interruptNumber, uint32_t esp);

        static void IgnoreInterruptRequest();
        static void HandleInterruptRequest0x00();
        static void HandleInterruptRequest0x01();
    };
#endif
```

Вот последнее обновление сообщений об ошибках:

```
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/myOS_8.0T$ make mykernel.bin
as --32 -o interruptstubs.o interruptstubs.s
interruptstubs.s: Assembler messages:
interruptstubs.s: Warning: конец файла не в конце строки; вставлен символ новой строки
interruptstubs.s:22: Error: bad register name `%0x20+IRQ_BASE'
interruptstubs.s:23: Error: bad register name `%0x21+IRQ_BASE'
Makefile:12: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «interruptstubs.o»
make: *** [interruptstubs.o] Ошибка 1
sergey@COMPUTER:~/Рабочий стол/myOS_8.0T$
```

В чём моя ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо

Comment: А что вы подразумевали под `movb %\num + IRQ_BASE, (interruptnumber)` команды mov должны оперировать как минимум с одним регистром. тут регистра в помине нет. А даже если `%\num` вдруг окажеться регистром, то операции `movb eax+IRQ_BASE, x` то же быть не может, имена регистров ни с чем складывать нельзя. Если же имелось ввиду обращение по некому адресу, содержащемуся в регистре, то где квадратные скобки

Comment: @Mike подскажите пожалуйста где должны быть квадратные скобки, пожалуйста приведите пример

Comment: Для начала скажите что же вы хотите сделать. Квадратные скобки нужны когада вы собраетесь занести значение по адресу, находящемуся в регистре. Но у вас же там в принципе нет регистра. Так что возможно вам нужно что то совершенно другое

Comment: Этот файл выводит сообщение из файла cpp в месте с ядром которое тоже написано на cpp но это не загрузчик короче там работа с прерываниям если всё работает хорошо то должно вывестись сообщение из kernel.cpp и из этого файла cpp который я опубликовал

Comment: Я спрашивал конкретно про строку `movb %\num + IRQ_BASE, (interruptnumber)` что она должна делать

Comment: Да я и сам толком не знаю видео урок по которому я это писал там всё по английски

Comment: По видеоурокам вы все равно ничему не научитесь. Надо читать техническую литературу, понимать принципы работы процессора. Изучить ассемблер. После этого можно пробовать уже что то писать, по крайней мере зная что вы делаете. Вероятность что что то заработает так как надо после видеоурока очень мала и даже если заработает, но вы не будете понимать каждой строчки написанного то пользы для вас от этого не будет никакой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на строку номер 8:

```
.global _ZN16InterruptManager22IgnoreInterruptRequestEv:
```

Посмотрите на сообщение об ошибке:

```
interruptstubs.s:8: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `:'
```

Вам говорят, что в конце строки объявления глобального символа, двоеточие не нужно.

Comment: Это единственная ошибка, а как же IRQ_BASE

Comment: Сейчас попробую как вы советуете @zed

Comment: @Сергей Про остальные ошибки ничего не могу сказать.

Comment: Спасибо @zed я исправил ошибку про двоеточие оно пропало